# Error: no default constructor exists for class Mesh, attempting to pass Mesh as a parameter into a different constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a class "Object"

```
Object::Object(Transform transform, Mesh mesh, Shader shader)
{
    this->transform = transform;
    this->mesh = mesh;
    this->shader = shader;
}
```

with 3 member variables Transform, Mesh and Shader (in case it's relevant I'm working with OpenGL- GLEW and GLFW)

The above constructor returns a "no default constructor exists for class Mesh" error.

I've defined a constructor for mesh, but my confusion here is that I'm trying to assign a passed variable object Mesh into the constructor when I instantiate an object.

Essentially I want something like

```
Transform transform() //has a default constructor requiring no parameters
Mesh mesh(parameters)
Shader shader()
Object myObject(transform, mesh, shader);
```

As a generic example.

In case the Mesh constructor is relevant:

```
Mesh::Mesh(Vertex* verts, unsigned int numVerts)
{

    /*Vertex vertices[] = { Vertex(glm::vec3(-.5,-.5,0)),
                            Vertex(glm::vec3(0,.5,0)),
                            Vertex(glm::vec3(.5,-.5,0)) };*/
    //vertices = new Vertex[numVerts]{ verts };

    m_drawCount = numVerts;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vertexArrayObject);
    glBindVertexArray(m_vertexArrayObject);

    glGenBuffers(NUM_BUFFERS, m_vertexArrayBuffers);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexArrayBuffers[position_VB]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numVerts * sizeof(verts[0]), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

tl;dr I'm coming from a C# background, so maybe I've gotten confused but I'm not sure why I would need a default constructor for an object when I'm passing an object in as a parameter when that same object can be instantiated *with the constructor I defined* elsewhere in my code.

Comment: Can you point out where in you code the error is being reported?

Comment: Jasper, the error was being displayed at the opening bracket of the Object constructor. John's answer below cleared things up and it is working now, thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
Object::Object(Transform transform, Mesh mesh, Shader shader)
{
    this->transform = transform;
    this->mesh = mesh;
    this->shader = shader;
}
```

Should be written like this instead:

```
Object::Object(const Transform& t, const Mesh& m, const Shader& s)
    : transform(t), mesh(m), shader(s)
{
}
```

C++ isn't like C#, and you're going to get very confused if you assume it is.

In C++, all subobjects are constructed *before you enter the body of the constructor*. So the subobjects of your `Object` class (`transform`, `mesh`, and `shader`) are constructed using default constructors because you didn't specify anything else. The *assignments* that you coded in the body of your constructor have no effect on this.

To specify different parameters for the constructors of your subobjects, use a [*member initializer list*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), like my code above shows.

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need to rename the parameters: `Object::Object(Transform transform, Mesh mesh, Shader shader)  : transform(transform), mesh(mesh), shader(shader) {}` works, because in a member initialization list, the compiler unambiguously knows which identifiers are members and which are parameters, so they are allowed to have the same names.